# Spark streaming not picking the new files from cloud storage source

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, spark-streaming

The spark structured streaming job is not picking the new files from google cloud storage source bucket when the checkpoint is default checkpoint.

If I provide new checkpoint location, the streaming does well without issues. Not sure where I am missing?

Comment: Could you please provide your code, as well as the error you are getting while you use the default checkpoint?

Comment: I am not getting any error here.

Comment: Right now is really hard to understand what product you're using, what's your issue and what might be the cause. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to help you out.